# c++ const char * assigment operator overload

Tags: c++

How to deal with `const char *` ?

```
Obj(const Obj& o); // <--
Obj& operator=(const Obj& o);// <-- How to do it right?

// Obj(const Obj& o); // <--
// Obj& operator=(const Obj& o);

class Obj
{
protected:
  const char * name;
  const char * desc;
public:
  Obj(const char * _name,
      const char * _desc)
  :name(_name)
  ,desc(_desc)
  {
    //
  }

  Obj(const Obj& o); // <--
  Obj& operator=(const Obj& o);// <-- Have no idea how to implement this...

  virtual ~Obj(){}
};

class B:public Obj
{
    float v1, v2;
    B(float a, float b)
    :v1(a)
    ,v2(h)
    ,Obj("B","class")
    {
      //
    }

};
```

Update

```
T& operator=(const T& other)            // copy assignment
{
  if (this != &other)
  { // self-assignment check expected
    if (other.size != size)
    {                                   // storage cannot be reused
        delete[] mArray;                // destroy storage in this
        size = 0;
        mArray = nullptr;               // preserve invariants in case next line throws
        mArray = new int[other.size];   // create storage in this
        size = other.size;
    }
    std::copy(other.mArray, other.mArray + other.size, mArray);
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: Use std::string.

Comment: yep, change `const char *` to `std::string` and the automatically generated copy and assignment operators will work, no need to implement them yourself

Comment: Just `Obj& operator=(const Obj& o) = default;`. Just copy pointers. Why is destructor virtual?

Comment: I not sure... but default will do the shallow copy, but I need a deep copy. String is forbidden and STL also.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: your code has a serious bug in the form of `Obj("B","class")` , it assings to the members external pointers rather than copying their data.  Forget *all* about it, including my answer, and use `std::string`.

<s>Copying objects with pointers means that you want to serialize the pointer data. In case it's a string, a strcpy/memcpy would suffice:</s>

```
Obj& operator=(const Obj& o)
{ 
name = new char[o.namesize + 1]; // must keep the size unless it's a string, so you can assume the size with strlen().
strcpy_s(name,o.namesize + 1,o.name); 
namesize = o.namesize;


 // With strlen
 name = new char[strlen(o.name) + 1];
 strcpy_s(name,strlen(o.name) + 1,o.name);

return *this;
}
```

However, always use `std::string` and forget about all this stuff since it will be handled automatically by STL, including move semantics, automatic memory management etc.

Comment: Since `char*` lives firmly in the C world it's probably better to use `malloc` or `calloc` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Can you be assured you can `free` something allocated with `new`?

Comment: @tadman • you should never `free` something allocated with `new` or `new[]`.

Comment: @Eljay That's why I'm saying if you are using C strings, where C code might be touching it and potentially taking ownership of the allocation, then you should use something compatible with `free` so as not to sabotage that.

Comment: @tadman • but there is nothing in the question to suggest the C-style strings in the Obj class are being passed to C code that will be deallocating them.

Comment: @Eljay It's just the *When in Rome* principle. Using C strings? Use C allocators.